# Linux: permission to read file from /sys/kernel/debug wihout root privileges

Tags: linux, permissions, root

I'd like to read small text file, located at: `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` **without** root permissions. It contains information about graphic cards (dedicated ATI Radeon and integrated Intel HD3000).
I wrote a simple script displaying infomation I need, but it works only with root privileges. I already tried changing file & folder permissions, but when I restart my computer, the problem remains. Is it possible to permanently change that file permissions or owner?

Why do I need that?
To bind that script with keyboard shortcut and get following Ubuntu 'dialog' after pressing key combination:

[image]

What is inside `switch` file? As I said before, it's just simple text file, with following content:

> 0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
>
> 1:DIS: :Off:0000:01:00.0

My script `status-radeon.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
CONTENT=`cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch | cut -d ':' -f 1-4 `
DISPLAY=:0 notify-send -t 4000 -i /home/Greg/Pictures/ati_radeon.png "GPU status" "$CONTENT"
echo "$CONTENT"
```

My `/etc/sudoers.tmp` content, without comments starting with #. It starts with `nano` editor, but I don't think it's relevant.

```
Defaults        env_reset                                             
Defaults        mail_badpass Defaults       
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL 
Greg    ALL=(ALL:ALL)   ALL 
Greg    ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/Greg/Scripts/status-radeon.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the permissions of system folders is not a good idea. Why don't you just setup a crontab for root that copies the file's contents somewhere else and have your script read from that?

```
$ sudo crontab -e
```

Add a line like this:

```
 */5 * * * * cp /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch /home/YOUR_USER/switch
```

Now, every time you reboot, that file will be copied to your home directory (remember to replace `YOUR_USER` with your actual username) and you can access it there.

Comment: I've added at the end of file line: `@reboot cp /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch /home/Greg/Scripts/switch`. After saving file and rebooting computer, no new file was added to `/home/Greg/Scripts/`.

Comment: @gogowitczak, not sure what's wrong here and I don't want to debug it in this question. Try posting a new question about why a crontab fails to run and I would be happy to help you there. Also, try adding a similar crontab with a simple commmand, for example `@reboot ls /usr > /home/Greg/usr_contents` and check if that is executed after reboot.

Comment: @gogowitczak, see updated answer.

Comment: When I ran script with sudo, it works fine (see screenshot). After adding your modifications, when I execute script `./status-radeon.sh`, it prompts for root password.

Comment: @gogowitczak, sorry, my updated answer is just wrong (and will be deleted), I tried it on my machine and it worked because I still had root priviledges (*idiot*). Maybe the problem with cron is that it is running before the file is created. Try replacing the `@reboot` line with `*/5 * * * * cp /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch /home/YOUR_USER/switch` to make it run every 5 minutes.

Comment: ok, it's working now. However, it's still a workaround. Thanks a lot for your efford!

Comment: This is an awful answer. Much of the reason one would want to read from `/sys/kernel/debug` is for things that update often.

Comment: @whoKnows sorry? Why is that relevant? This will copy the file every five minutes. If you need to poll it more often, please ask a new question, there are many ways of doing that. What you _never_ want to do is change the permissions of a system directory just so your user can access it. That is simply never a good idea.

Comment: @terdon Why is it "never a good idea"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo` to allow some users (e.g., you) to run the script as root

```
$ visudo
```

and then add

```
username  ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/your/script
```

For a short introduction to `sudo`: http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/intro.html

Comment: It's not working. I've added at the end of file:
`Greg     ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/Greg/Scripts/status-radeon.sh` and rebooted my machine.

Comment: No need to reboot. And what do you mean by "it's not working". Any error? Which system are you using? BTW there is a space between the = and NOPASSWD:

Comment: @Matteo: I've added the missing space. Error: `cat: /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch: Access denied`. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 x64.
@terdon: I've ran successfully `sudo chmod 4755 status-radeon.sh`, still not working.

Comment: @gogowitczak, hmm,I think we are falling afoul of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What exactly are you trying to do here? Why do you need to read that file? There should be a workaround...

Comment: @terdon - I've added a detailed info to original post.